# Table created with vtable package does not appear

Tags: tables, errors, rstudio

I used to work with stargazer, but this package (vtable) is better for making summarization by groups. I choose "latex" as out and the following table was generated. However, my overleaf article did not recognize the table as several erros appeared. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
 \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1} 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ 

\caption{Summary Statistics}

\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
\hline
\hline
Variable & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl. 25} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl. 75} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{c}{aliado: 0} \\ 
ano & 36423 & 2008.478 & 4.945 & 2000 & 2005 & 2012 & 2018 \\ 
orientacao & 36423 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Centro & 8337 & 22.9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Direita & 14578 & 40\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esquerda & 13508 & 37.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
code & 36423 & 3216561.645 & 971270.128 & 1100023 & 2506103 & 4109302 & 5222302 \\ 
code\_6 & 36423 & 321655.708 & 97127.013 & 110002 & 250610 & 410930 & 522230 \\ 
servico & 36423 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água & 26633 & 73.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água e Esgoto & 9782 & 26.9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esgoto & 8 & 0\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
paralisacao\_duracao & 9470 & 29.03 & 220.606 & 0 & 6.67 & 14 & 6668.44 \\ 
intermitencia\_duracao & 5296 & 66.535 & 595.074 & 0 & 3.2 & 13 & 31542.86 \\ 
cloro\_residual & 28060 & 4.887 & 14.346 & 0 & 0 & 2.24 & 100 \\ 
turbidez & 28145 & 7.053 & 17.494 & 0 & 0 & 4.12 & 100 \\ 
reparos\_esgotos\_duracao & 3956 & 12.598 & 41.359 & 0 & 1.85 & 11 & 1213.02 \\ 
servico\_duracao & 15046 & 53.879 & 289.9 & 0 & 1.03 & 58.373 & 22861.5 \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\multicolumn{8}{c}{aliado: 1} \\ 
ano & 7256 & 2007.959 & 4.923 & 2000 & 2004 & 2012 & 2018 \\ 
orientacao & 7256 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Centro & 3300 & 45.5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Direita & 314 & 4.3\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esquerda & 3642 & 50.2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
code & 7256 & 3185174.31 & 981385.162 & 1100049 & 2413557 & 4127304 & 5221700 \\ 
code\_6 & 7256 & 318516.978 & 98138.517 & 110004 & 241355 & 412730 & 522170 \\ 
servico & 7256 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água & 5809 & 80.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água e Esgoto & 1443 & 19.9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esgoto & 4 & 0.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
paralisacao\_duracao & 1395 & 36.507 & 247.343 & 0 & 6 & 16 & 4568.29 \\ 
intermitencia\_duracao & 753 & 66.844 & 714.663 & 0 & 3 & 12 & 18360 \\ 
cloro\_residual & 5144 & 5.345 & 14.739 & 0 & 0 & 2.872 & 100 \\ 
turbidez & 5120 & 8.025 & 17.778 & 0 & 0 & 6.005 & 100 \\ 
reparos\_esgotos\_duracao & 396 & 33.269 & 68.916 & 0 & 2 & 21.088 & 405.98 \\ 
servico\_duracao & 2516 & 66.857 & 396.499 & 0 & 1 & 49.752 & 14540.2\\ 
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular} %
}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not use `\resizebox` to make a table fit into the textwidth. This will result in inconsistent font sizes throughout your document. There are better ways to make an overly wide table narrower like using `tabularx` or introducing linebreaks in column headers, manually adjusting font size and the value of tablcolsep. If your table is narrower and you want to stretch it to textwidth, you might be interested in `tabular*` in combination with `\extracolsep{\fill}}` instead. Especially, don't place the `\caption` command inside of the `resizebox` as this is the reason for all the error messages.

Comment: I have removed `beamer` from the tags since you used the `article` documentclass in your MWE. I also removed `overleaf` since this error is not IDE specific.

Comment: Removing resizebox worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error message, place the `\caption` command outside of the `\resizebox`. Even better would be removing the `\resizbox` alltogether since the use of it on tables will only result in inconsistent font sizes throughtout the document. Additonally, your table already is as wide as the textwidth, so \resizebox` does not have any effect here.

In the following MWE, I also replaced the `\hline` commands with lines from the `booktabs` package, that you already loaded. I also made some commented changes to your preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed any more in a recent installation
%\usepackage{graphics}% replaced with graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%\usepackage{array}% already loaded by tabularx.
\usepackage{hyperref} % Should, with just a few exceptions, be the last package in your preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
\toprule
Variable & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl. 25} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl. 75} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{aliado: 0} \\ 
\midrule
ano & 36423 & 2008.478 & 4.945 & 2000 & 2005 & 2012 & 2018 \\ 
orientacao & 36423 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Centro & 8337 & 22.9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Direita & 14578 & 40\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esquerda & 13508 & 37.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
code & 36423 & 3216561.645 & 971270.128 & 1100023 & 2506103 & 4109302 & 5222302 \\ 
code\_6 & 36423 & 321655.708 & 97127.013 & 110002 & 250610 & 410930 & 522230 \\ 
servico & 36423 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água & 26633 & 73.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água e Esgoto & 9782 & 26.9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esgoto & 8 & 0\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
paralisacao\_duracao & 9470 & 29.03 & 220.606 & 0 & 6.67 & 14 & 6668.44 \\ 
intermitencia\_duracao & 5296 & 66.535 & 595.074 & 0 & 3.2 & 13 & 31542.86 \\ 
cloro\_residual & 28060 & 4.887 & 14.346 & 0 & 0 & 2.24 & 100 \\ 
turbidez & 28145 & 7.053 & 17.494 & 0 & 0 & 4.12 & 100 \\ 
reparos\_esgotos\_duracao & 3956 & 12.598 & 41.359 & 0 & 1.85 & 11 & 1213.02 \\ 
servico\_duracao & 15046 & 53.879 & 289.9 & 0 & 1.03 & 58.373 & 22861.5 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{aliado: 1} \\ 
\midrule
ano & 7256 & 2007.959 & 4.923 & 2000 & 2004 & 2012 & 2018 \\ 
orientacao & 7256 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Centro & 3300 & 45.5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Direita & 314 & 4.3\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esquerda & 3642 & 50.2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
code & 7256 & 3185174.31 & 981385.162 & 1100049 & 2413557 & 4127304 & 5221700 \\ 
code\_6 & 7256 & 318516.978 & 98138.517 & 110004 & 241355 & 412730 & 522170 \\ 
servico & 7256 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água & 5809 & 80.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Água e Esgoto & 1443 & 19.9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
... Esgoto & 4 & 0.1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
paralisacao\_duracao & 1395 & 36.507 & 247.343 & 0 & 6 & 16 & 4568.29 \\ 
intermitencia\_duracao & 753 & 66.844 & 714.663 & 0 & 3 & 12 & 18360 \\ 
cloro\_residual & 5144 & 5.345 & 14.739 & 0 & 0 & 2.872 & 100 \\ 
turbidez & 5120 & 8.025 & 17.778 & 0 & 0 & 6.005 & 100 \\ 
reparos\_esgotos\_duracao & 396 & 33.269 & 68.916 & 0 & 2 & 21.088 & 405.98 \\ 
servico\_duracao & 2516 & 66.857 & 396.499 & 0 & 1 & 49.752 & 14540.2\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} %

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```